# large content not moving to next page in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm generating pdf from html. problem is if there is any large content then it's not showing properly. Firstly an blank page appearing then content overlapping footer but full text not showing. The rest content are hiding down , not moving to next page. I've tried `page-break-after:always; page-break-inside:avoid;`

any idea on this issue?

check below code:-

```
$html = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry

ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ  ÆØÅ ÆØÅ ";

pdfGenerate($html);

function pdfGenerate($html="")
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();


    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("Arial");
    $canvas->page_text(510, 775, "{PAGE_NUM} av {PAGE_COUNT}",
                   $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Without any more detail it's unlikely to know what the issue is. Any example HTML?

Comment: @apokryfos check my edit

Comment: close and negative vote appreciated. But do U have any answer of this question?

Comment: You haven't provided any HTML. Just text. I don't see where you tried the page-break styles.

Comment: it's just an example of my application. the application and code is too big. so not able to post it here

Comment: If the content isn't paging correctly then it's important to see at least a representative sample of the code. There's not really a general answer that would apply to your question.

Answer (score 0):

For me i modified a litter the code but in essence work well.
dompdf generate a pdf with 2 pages

```
$dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$options = new \Dompdf\Options();
$fontMetrics = new Dompdf\FontMetrics($canvas,$options);
$font = $fontMetrics->getFont('Arial');
$canvas->page_text(510, 775, "{PAGE_NUM} av {PAGE_COUNT}",
               $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

One important thing is that your example is plain text and i think is more accurate using html (a full html page)